# I am unable to generate the Access Token for conversion api in my Facebook pixel's conversion api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, ads

I am getting the message as

Missing prerequisite
You can't generate an access token because you don't have admin access to your selected pixel's
business account. To generate an access token, ask an existing admin for this business account to grant you admin access.

The irony is that I am the owner of that business account. If anyone knows how to solve this problem the please inform me as it will be very helpful.

I tried to generate the access token for conversion api in pixel's setting because I wanted to link it with the wordpress plugin PixelYourSite but failed to do so because fb was saying that I don't have access to that business account. but I am the owner

Answer (score 0):

You have to also create a separate Business Account in Meta. Once you do that, you can link it to your personal one by adding yourself as a user and then you can include any FB pages you manage as well as your Instagram.

To set up the business account, go to https://business.facebook.com/overview and click Create Account. It seems scary because you already have a regular Facebook account, but once you add yourself as a user, they will be linked.

If you need them to help walk you through it, you can start a Messenger chat with them here:
https://business.facebook.com/fbe/support