# Can't generate direct access token for Facebook Conversion API

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

When trying to generate the access token for direct integration of the Facebook / Meta Pixel Conversion API, it keeps giving me the following error message:

> You can’t generate an access token because you don’t have admin access to your selected pixel’s business account. To generate an access token, ask an existing admin for this business account to grant you admin access.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

What the error message says is obviously not true because I am, in fact, the owner and admin of that business account and creator of that pixel - so I clearly have admin rights.

I noticed that other people have run into the same issue, as it was asked months ago already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455230/i-am-unable-to-generate-the-access-token-for-conversion-api-in-my-facebook-pixel), but unfortunately, nobody has been able to provide a solution (the only answer given there was not helpful).

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks!